# Virtuemart conflicts in dropdown only sometimes

Tags: javascript, virtuemart

I am using Virtuemart and enalbled a "Multi-Variant" options.
It nearly works, in the sense that only sometimes the product page (which has the custom options dropdowns) gives a JavaScript error. Some other times it works as expected.
I have never seen something giving an error ONLY sometimes, I am explaining it due to the fact that anothet JavaScript hasn't finieshed loading and doesn't give conflict...

The error is: **jQuery(...).chosen is not a function**

I Cannot show you the page because it' protected and under cnostruction, but I can show you the snipped of Javascipt giving the conflict...

```
< script id="updateChosen_js" type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[ 
if (typeof Virtuemart === "undefined")
    var Virtuemart = {};
    Virtuemart.updateChosenDropdownLayout = function() {
        var vm2string = {editImage: 'edit image',select_all_text: 'Select all',select_some_options_text: 'Available for all'};
        jQuery(".vm-chzn-select").each( function () {
            var swidth = jQuery(this).css("width")+10;
            jQuery(this).chosen({enable_select_all: true,select_all_text : vm2string.select_all_text,select_some_options_text:vm2string.select_some_options_text,disable_search_threshold: 5, width: swidth});
        });
    }
    Virtuemart.updateChosenDropdownLayout(); //]]>
```

Comment: Please check this file is being loaded on the page: `/media/jui/js/chosen.jquery.min.js`

Comment: yes it's loaded by VirtueMart:

`/components/com_virtuemart/assets/js/chosen.jquery.min.js?vmver=9194`

Comment: Try wrapping the code you provided inside `jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ... });`

Comment: u can disable dropdowns/regions libs (js of course) in virtuemart cfg (templates tab) and now no error

Answer (score 2):

First check if you have two jQuery versions by pressing CTRL + U (it shows the source code on Chrome), normally jQuery chosen is not a function because JQuery.fn doesn't know who is chosen function, that means sometimes jQuery conflict. In VM3 have a option to enable the jQuery library in website, uncheck this option in shop, search by others components or modules that you've installed recently, only keep jui/js/jquery... (min.js, no-conflict, migrate), if you tried so much and can't remove you can force the disable with unset() function at index.php of your template from the others jQuery of others extensions/plugins etc.

example:

```
<?php unset($this->_scripts['/media/system/js/mootools-core.js']); ?>
```